# Group By splits the first column twice

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, group-by

```
+----+---------+---------+---------+
| id | column1 | column2 | column3 |
+----+---------+---------+---------+
|  1 | Main1   | Sub1    | Sub1_6  |
|  2 | Main2   | Sub1    | Sub1_5  |
|  3 | Main3   | Sub5    | Sub5_1  |
|  4 | Main1   | Sub2    | Sub2_6  |
|  5 | Main2   | Sub1    | Sub1_3  |
|  6 | Main2   | Sub1    | Sub1_1  |
|  7 | Main1   | Sub1    | Sub1_3  |
+----+---------+---------+---------+
```

In this case I would like to display something like this;

- Main1 - (3)

  - Sub1 - (2)

    - Sub1_6 - (1)
    - Sub1_3 - (1)
  - Sub2 - (1)

    - Sub2_6 - (1)
- Main2 - (3)

  - Sub1 - (3)

    - Sub1_5 - (1)
    - Sub1_3 - (1)
    - Sub1_1 - (1)
- Main3 - (1)

  - Sub5 - (1)

    - Sub5_1 - (1)

---

I have tried following codes but it splits everything.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

$con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT column1,column2,column3,COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY column1,column2,column3');
foreach($sql as $row) {
    echo "<ul>";
    echo "<li>" . $row['column1'] . " - (" . $row['COUNT(*)'] . ")</li>";
    echo "<ul>";
    echo "<li>" . $row['column2'] . " - (" . $row['COUNT(*)'] . ")</li>";
    echo "<ul>";
    echo "<li>" . $row['column3'] . " - (" . $row['COUNT(*)'] . ")</li>";
    echo "</ul>";
    echo "</ul>";
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

It looks like this with these codes, so the problem is; it splits Main1 twice in this case and I would like to group them and show as subs.

- Main1 - (2)

  - Sub1 - (2)

    - Sub1_6 - (1)
    - Sub1_3 - (1)
- Main1 - (1)

  - Sub2 - (1)

    - Sub2_6 - (1)
- Main2 - (3)

  - Sub1 - (3)

    - Sub1_5 - (1)
    - Sub1_3 - (1)
    - Sub1_1 - (1)
- Main3 - (1)

  - Sub5 - (1)

    - Sub5_1 - (1)

---

It might have more than 2 subs, so I need something dynamic.

Comment: You have to change your code such that it does _not_ create output right away but instead saves all entries you read from the database in an internal, temporary array. That allows to sum up entries that belong together. Then, in a second step, you can iterate through that array and create the actual output.

Comment: `ORDER BY column1,column2,column3` might make life a little easier

Comment: `COUNT(*) as cnt` would make the `row['COUNT(*)']` into `row['cnt']` not gona fix anything but would make things easier to read

Comment: How are you getting different counts? Across all column groupings they should share same `Count(*)`.